# Jquery slider boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, slider

Not sure if this is a javascript issue or can be solved with CSS.

Im using an image with a text overlay slider but seem to having some issues with where the slider starts on page load. This is the live example, I would like the slider to be hidden on load and appear from below on rollover.

http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/detail-shoppe/directors

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the initial `top` value to your CSS, like this:

```
.boxcaption{
  top: 240px;     /* add this! */
  float: left;
  ....
 }
```

This should give you the initial effect you want, and on hover it'll slide up on the first hover.

Answer (score 0):

Just include this line which sets the inital css so that the two `.cover` divs are "hidden"

```
$('.boxgrid.captionfull .cover').css('top', 240);
```

like this

```
...
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.boxgrid.captionfull .cover').css('top', 240);
    //Full Caption Sliding (Hidden to Visible)
...
```